# Sip settings without domain name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sip, voip

I want to develop a VOIP application for iPhone.
I used the Sip library from Linphone but I can't register without a domain name. The server has no domain.

Is there a way to allow the user to register with only the username, password and Server IP?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use the IP Address as the domain name?

Comment: What kind of SIP server are you trying to connect to? Usually it should declare a domain, even if fake. You could also try with sip:user@ipaddress.

Comment: I tried to use the IP as the domain name, it doesn't work. I tried finding the domain name with nslookup, it says domain doesn't exist. How could I find out this fake domain?

Answer (score 0):

Use your IP address as domain name! In Kamailio, Opensips or Asterisk you just set IP and aliases (usually other IP or Domain Names) to listen SIP requests.

Regards

Comment: machado in opensips and kamilio based on authentication parameter it depends weather domain name is required or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to register without domain name.in opensips sip server. Config you have to set:

```
modparam("auth_db", "use_domain", 0)
```

If true (not 0), domain will be also used when looking up in the subscriber table. If you have a multi-domain setup, it is strongly recommended to turn on this parameter to avoid username overlapping between domains.

So it depends what your server configuration is. Basically it is asking for you sip server domain name. If it doesn't have any domain name then it must have to enable domain name lookup.